# Right to left scrolling text effect

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate, right-to-left

I am trying to scroll text (list elements actually) from right to left.

Here is HTML code

```
<div id="slider-txt">
    <ul>
        <li class="islide">text 1</li>
        <li class="islide">text 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my CSS

```
#slider-txt
{
position:relative;
width: 590px;
}

#slider-txt ul
{
list-style-type: none;
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#slider-txt ul li
{
text-align: right;
}
```

and the jQuery

```
var box = $('#slider-txt');
    if (box.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
var ul = box.find('ul');
    var li = $('#slider-txt').find('li');

    var liWidth = box.width();
    var ulWidth = liWidth * li.length;
    li.css('width', liWidth);
    ul.css('width', ulWidth);
    li.css('display', 'inline-block');
var liElement = 0;

    function slideNxt() {
        liElement++;
        if (liElement == li.length) {
            liElement = 0;
        }
    var curLeftPos = ul.css('left').split('px')[0];
    var newLeftPos = -(liElement * liWidth);
    ul.animate({ left: newOffset + 'px' }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'swing' });
}
setInterval(slideNxt, 2000);
```

The above code swings the list items right to left and left to right in loop. The inline-block property set on list items don't seem to work as expected (List items are displayed one below another). Also I want the list item to get hidden if it goes out of the box (div#slider-txt) width, which is not happening.

Can you please help me fixing these issues? Thanks...

Comment: Use `marquee` tag of HTML. (LOL)

Comment: sorry buddy, but I want to implement it with jQuery as I will be adding some more effects to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS needs to be edited... and we will get the scrolling effect.

```
#slider-txt
{
   width: 590px;
   height: 20px;
   display:block;
   overflow:hidden; /* to hide the text */
   position: relative;
}

#slider-txt ul
{
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   position: absolute;
}

#slider-txt ul li
{
   text-align: center;
   float: left; /* brings the list items in one line */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be using marque, it's not very user intuitive. Instead I suggest you have a giant rotating lollipop, written in CSS3 duh!

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/AA6KL

I couldn't resist.

Comment: I've updated your Fiddle for more awesomeness : [http://jsfiddle.net/AA6KL/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/AA6KL/2/)

Comment: That is pure awesomeness. A marque lollipop of doom. You sir are winning.